# mysql group 2 rows into 1 with only one different value between the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT Club_Name, SUM(Data_km) AS km, Type_id
FROM Data
INNER JOIN Clubs ON Data.Data_Club = Clubs.Club_id
INNER JOIN Types ON Clubs.Club_Type = Types.Type_id
WHERE Club_isActive = 1
GROUP BY Club_Name, Type_id
```

which gives me this table:

| club_name | km | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| A | 15 | 2 |
| B | 80 | 1 |
| B | 34 | 2 |
| C | 36 | 1 |

And I'm trying to achieve:

| club_name | type 1 km | type 2 km |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 15 |
| B | 80 | 34 |
| C | 36 |  |

not all clubs will have a type 2.
How do I rewrite the query to achieve the reorganization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Club_Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type_id = 1 THEN Data_km END) as km_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type_id = 2 THEN Data_km END) as km_2
FROM Data d JOIN
     Clubs c
     ON d.Data_Club = c.Club_id JOIN
     Types t
     ON c.Club_Type = t.Type_id
WHERE Club_isActive = 1
GROUP BY Club_Name;
```